# Filter Add Existing Button On A One To Many Relationship

Tags: filter, addition, dynamics-crm-2011, lookup

I'm having a strange problem with CRM 2011. What I'm trying to do is filter a lookup on an add existing button for a one to many relationship. I've followed the instructions found on this blog...

http://danielcai.blogspot.com/2011/12/filtered-lookup-for-existing-button-of.html?showComment=1331333531276#c7259013963486793093

and for many to many relationships it works great. For one to many though I can get the lookup to be filtered, but as soon as I select an item the "Add" button gets greyed out. I've been trying to get it figured out for a while now but can't seem to resolve the issue. Anyone have any advice?